# formulario php se envía pero vacío!

Tags: php, html

Estoy intentando enviar un correo por medio de un formulario de contacto en php.

El correo **se envía** y **llega**, pero este **lo hace vacío**.

He revisado el código cambiado algunas cosas, pero no logro hacer que se envíe con su contenido.

## HTML:

```
<div class="speech-bubble">
<h3 class="sub-title">Contactar</h3>

<form id="contactForm" name="contactform" data-toggle="validator" class="popup-form" action="process.php">
<div class="row">
    
    <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
        <input name="fname" id="fname" placeholder="Tu nombre*" class="form-control" type="text" required data-error="Por favor ingresa tu nombre"> 
        <div class="input-group-icon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></div>
    </div><!-- end form-group -->
    
    <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
        <input name="email" id="email" placeholder="Tu E-mail*" pattern=".*@\w{2,}\.\w{2,}" class="form-control" type="email" required data-error="Por favor ingresa un correo electrónico válido">
        <div class="input-group-icon"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></div>
    </div><!-- end form-group -->
    <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
        <input name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="Teléfono" class="form-control" type="text">
        <div class="input-group-icon"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i></div> 
    </div><!-- end form-group -->
    <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
        <select name="subject" id="subject" placeholder="Asunto*" class="form-control" type="text" required data-error="Por favor ingresa el asunto">
            <option value="Consulta General">Consulta General</option>
            <option value="Realizar Pedido">Realizar Pedido</option>
            <option value="Informe un problema">Informe un problema</option>
        </select>
        <div class="input-group-icon"><i class="fa fa-book"></i></div> 
        </div><!-- end form-group -->
    <div class="form-group col-sm-12">
        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
        <textarea rows="3" name="message" id="message" placeholder="Escribe tu comentario aquí*" class="form-control" required data-error="Por favor ingresa un mensaje"></textarea>
        <div class="textarea input-group-icon"><i class="fa fa-pencil-alt"></i></div>
    </div><!-- end form-group -->
    
    <div class="form-group last col-sm-12">
        <button type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-custom"><i class='fa fa-envelope'></i> Enviar</button>
    </div><!-- end form-group -->   

    <span class="sub-text">* Campos requeridos</span>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div><!-- end row -->
```

## proccess.php:

```
<?php
@$Nombre = htmlspecialchars($_POST['fname']);
@$Correo = htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']);
@$Empresa = htmlspecialchars($_POST['phone']);
@$Motivo = htmlspecialchars($_POST['subject']);
@$Mensaje = htmlspecialchars($_POST['message']);

 $cabeceras = "From: $Correo\n" 
  . "Reply-To: $Correo\n";
  $asunto = "From: CONTACTO $Motivo\n"; 
  $email_to = "mi@correo.com\n"; 
  $contenido = "$Nombre ha enviado un mensaje desde el sitio web\n";
  . "\n"
  . "nombre: $Nombre\n"
  . "email: $Correo\n"
  . "telefono: $Empresa\n"
. "subject: $Motivo\n"
  . "message: $Mensaje\n"
. "\n";

 if (@mail($email_to, $asunto ,$contenido ,$cabeceras )) { 

echo '<div class="modal fade" id="respuesta2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"  aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
    <strong>Su mensaje ha sido enviado correctamente.</strong>
</div>    
</div>
</div>';
}else{

 echo '<div class="modal fade" id="respuesta2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
 <div class="modal-dialog">
 <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
    <strong>ERROR. Intente mas tarde.</strong>
 </div>    
 </div>
 </div>';
 }

  ?>
```

He buscado varias formas, y de todas esta fue la única que me "funcionó", ahora quisiera poder saber que está mal, gracias comunidad!

Comment: No sé de donde estás aprendiendo, sólo decirte que el uso de `@` es considerado una mala práctica en PHP porque dificulta la depuración, pues ese símbolo se pone para silenciar los errores. **Los errores no hay que silenciarlos, hay que resolverlos y controlarlos**. Aclarado eso, pregunto: ¿cómo se llama el archivo de tu código PHP? ¿Está en la misma carpeta que el archivo donde está el formulario? ¿Si en el PHP pones un `var_dump($_POST);` qué muestra?

Comment: También tienes un error concatenando el contenido, prueba a hacerlo así:  `$contenido = "$Nombre ha enviado un mensaje desde el sitio web\n"
  . "\n"
  . "nombre: $Nombre\n"
  . "email: $Correo\n"
  . "telefono: $Empresa\n"
. "subject: $Motivo\n"
  . "message: $Mensaje\n"
. "\n";`, quitando el `;` que hay en la primera línea, puesto que piensas seguir concatenando.

Comment: este formulario lo saque de una web, sin el @ tampoco me funciona, el error de concatenación lo reparé, gracias por la ayuda, y bueno el var_dump($_POST); me muestra array(0){}

Comment: Lo de quitar el `@` es una recomendación que te hago, para que aprendas a programar controlando los errores, no ignorándolos. O sea, un programador que programa ignorando los errores podemos decir que no es programador en realidad. No dije que ese sea el motivo de que no funcione. Si el `var_dump` no muestra nada **significa que los datos no se están enviando**. Si te fijas en el atributo `action` del formulario, verás que hay un archivo llamado `process.php` ... te pregunté **¿cómo se llama el archivo donde envías el email?** y no me has respondido. El archivo debe llamarse `process.php`

Comment: entiendo, concuerdo con tu comentario, gracias por la recomendación, y bueno el archivo efectivamente se llama process.php, aun sigo haciendo algunas pruebas y sigué sin funcionar.

Comment: ¿Y el formulario en qué archivo está?  ¿Es otro archivo?  ¿Los dos archivos están en la misma carpeta en tu servidor?

Comment: el formulario esta en index.html, ambos archivos estan en la misma carpeta raiz  de mi servidor(no es localhost) y el envío de email esta funcionando

Comment: ¿Dices que el email se envía pero llega vacío? Y un `var_dump($contenido);`  ¿qué muestra?

Comment: así es llega vacío, mira me el var_dump($contenido) me arroja esto: string(110) " ha enviado un mensaje desde el sitio web www.xxxx.com nombre: email: telefono: subject: message: "

Comment: Eso mismo debería mostrarse en el cuerpo de tu email puesto que está tomando bien los datos y dices que se envía. No entiendo entonces lo que esté pesando. ¿Seguro seguro que ese es el archivo y no otro? ¿Tienes un archivo llamado `errorlog` o parecido en tu carpeta raíz que puedas revisar? Es muy extraño esto. **Edita la pregunta poniendo el código como lo tienes ahora, corregido**.

Comment: Otra cosa que deberías hacer es quitar  la`\n` final en las variables `$asunto` y `$email_to`. Es poco probable que ese sea el motivo del error, pero no es necesario un salto de línea ahí y... nunca se sabe.

Answer (score 2):

El método por default siempre es `GET`, en tu formulario no estás mandándole el método por el cual quieres enviar, y al ignorar los errores no te das cuenta que las variables `$_POST` no existen, simplemente agrega el método

```
<form id="contactForm" name="contactform" method="POST" data-toggle="validator" class="popup-form" action="process.php">
```

Comment: Sip, esta es la respuesta buena seguro :) No me había fijado en el method. 
Aún así, no sé cómo le puede funcionar con el punto y coma cortando el string concatenado.

Comment: En los comentarios le ayudaron a solucionar el error de concatenación.

Comment: @JordiHuertas él corrigió lo de la concatenación a raíz de [este comentario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/204705/formulario-php-se-env%C3%ADa-pero-vac%C3%ADo?noredirect=1#comment382474_204705). Buena vista Sr1871, no me percaté de que faltaba el método, aunque sinceramente creía que cuando se mandaba por `GET` se podía recuperar por `POST` sin ningún problema. De todos modos esperamos confirmación del OP a ver si funcionó, porque es un problema que me tiene intrigado.

Comment: efectivamente fuer error de GET, y la concatenación ya la habia arreglado gracias a cedano, error solucionado! amigos  como les puedo dar puntaje a los que me ayudaron? cedano se paso varias molestias ayudandome

Comment: Puedes decirle que ponga su comentario como respuesta, y entonces le puedes dar puntuación.

Comment: Entonces marca esta respuesta como válida. Y en cuanto al ";", deberías haber modificado la pregunta y eliminarlo!

Answer (score 1):

Es un error muy claro, tienes un "**;**" que cierra la línea de código, por tanto el "**.**" para concatenar en la siguiente línea es incorrecto y produce un fatal error de sintaxis.

```
$contenido = "$Nombre ha enviado un mensaje desde el sitio web\n";
```

Ese "**;**" tienes que eliminarlo.

---

**NOTA**: Para poder ver los errores tienes que mostrar los errores en php. Puedes activarlo desde tu .ini o en cada archivo php por separado con:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

*Si tuveras activados los errores verías el error de PHP en el email.*